# I have to make a power function in C++ but it is not working

Tags: c++, function

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int power(int x, int y){
    int z;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i <= y; ++i){
        z *= x;
    }
    return(z);
}

int main() {
    cout << power(2,2);
    return 0;
}
```

This is a function that is supposed to calculate the power, however the output is 0 when it is supposed to be 4.

Comment: You haven't initialized `z`

Comment: But I initialized it inside the function, because I want the functions to have two parameters only

Comment: Sorry, you haven't. `int z;` is different from `int z = 1`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set z to some value to begin. You don't.

```
int z = 1; // or maybe x.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# include <iostream>


void power (int x , int y){
int x_0 = x;

for(int z=1; z<y ; z++){
     x*=x_0;
}
std::cout<<x<<std::endl;
}

int main(){
int baseNum =0, exponent =0;

std::cout<<" Enter base number:" <<std::endl;
std::cin>>baseNum;

std::cout<<" Enter exponent :" <<std::endl;
std::cin>>exponent;

power(baseNum, exponent);

}
```

Comment: `pow` is not a good choice for calculating integer powers.  It is subject to rounding errors (because it does the calculation in floating point).

Comment: I think that would be the case if you coerced a float or double into an int but not the other way round.

Comment: `return pow(x,y);` does a `double` to `int` conversion, which truncates the `double`.  In certain cases (depending on the exact value returned by `pow`), this returns 1 less than than the correct value.  More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).